# How to solve 2-5?

Tags: auditorium

This is what I've got after much trying:

[image]

It's kind of a miracle that it works at all, but I have no idea how to redirect the flow so that the purple icon gets some action as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use a single up-zone near the entrance to spread the rays over the whole stage.

You can see this in action at 3:18 on this video:

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Frank - He does actually explain it

Comment: @Frank link's been good for three years...  there's no reason to vote delete.  Put our past history aside.  Maybe you could play a game like auditorium and get chill.